# Symfony 2 - No execute find/querys after one getId

Tags: php, symfony

Next, when the program enters enters line 58, he enters a (verifyEntityAction) function to check if there is data in the table if there is it fills entering the function: insertOracle it runs everything right populates the table everything right, the problem is when I do the 195 line, when he makes the getId () it returns to IndexAction (with id just right ...) but does not execute line 64. (makes no query after that). Ever tried creating functions already tried everything in the store and I can not make it run. Below is the link. When I realize the second time the filter (ie qdo there already data in the table) it is a normal - 'and at that moment you try to persist and will not tb = [
If you can help me thank you very much.

Controller:
https://gist.github.com/viperdigo/19e88498bea3abdbc645